# Move image in a Column widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I wrapping this image with `Column` widget and I want to move only an image to fill space on top. See my screenshot. How to do that?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WBwE.png)

```
body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.3,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.5,
          child: Card(
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage("assets/images/Logoku.jpg"),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    text: "Posted on ",
                    children: [
                      TextSpan(
                        text: "17 June, 1999",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.pink),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Spacer(flex: 2),
                    Icon(Icons.chat),
                    Text("17"),
                    Spacer(flex: 1),
                    Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
                    Text("06"),
                    Spacer(flex: 2),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space on top caused by your mainAxisAligment

```
Column(               
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
```

What you can do is

```
Column(
                    //Delete mainAxisAlignment and use mainAxisSize
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, 
                    children: [

                    //Then you need to adjust spacing between widgets manually
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        child: Container(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage("assets/images/circles.png"),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                      //You can do it using sizedBox
                      SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 50,),
                      Text(
                        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),

                      //or Wrap your widget with Padding
                      Padding(
                         padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 50,),
                         child: RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            text: "Posted on ",
                            children: [
                               TextSpan(
                                  text: "17 June, 1999",
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.pink),
                               ),
                           ],
                         ),
                        ),
                      ),

                      //or Margin
                      Container(
                        margin: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 50,
                        child: Row(
                           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                           children: [
                              Spacer(flex: 2),
                              Icon(Icons.chat),
                              Text("17"),
                              Spacer(flex: 1),
                              Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
                              Text("06"),
                              Spacer(flex: 2),
                          ],
                         ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` .

It places the free space evenly between the childrenof your Column.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/MainAxisAlignment-class.html), this is the behavior of `MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly`:

> Place the free space evenly between the children as well as half of that space before and after the first and last child

This is why even when you use `Align` for the child, it will still operate based on the available space, which include the "half space" before the first child (which is your image). To achieve the behavior you want, update your UI with `Padding` and `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`:

```dart
// ... other lines

Card(
     clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
     child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
               Align(
        ...
```